# Don't hide keyboard on click action IOS 11

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic-native

After I click on Send button in ionic app keyboard is hide. My code:

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-labe>Text</ion-label>
    <ion-textarea [(ngModel)]="text" placeholder="Write a Message …"></ion-textarea>
</ion-item>
<a (click)="sendMessage();">Send</a>
```

I need the keyboard stay open after Click action. Help me please.

Answer (score 7):

I add textarea focus on Click action and its work perfectly. Code:

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-labe>Text</ion-label>
    <ion-textarea #index1 [(ngModel)]="text" placeholder="Write a Message …"></ion-textarea>
</ion-item>
<a (click)="sendMessage();index1.setFocus();">Send</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check Ionic Keyword plugin if you want to reopen keyword again  which give you many methods related to keyword like `cordova.plugins.Keyboard.show();`

https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-plugin-keyboard

and `sendMessage()` In this method what functionality you are doing which hiding keyword because in above code I am not getting any keyword related issue

Comment: I don`t need to reopen, I need that keyboard not hiding

Comment: yes that is why I am asking some detail about sendMessage() function

Comment: The keyboard is hiding if I click in any screen plays, not only on Click button